# How do I embed my shinyapps.io RShiny app within git-flavored markdown?

Tags: shiny, github-flavored-markdown

I have a small RShiny app up on shinyapps.io.

I would like to embed my app within Git flavored markdown, so I can post it on my blog.

Screenshots are nice and all, but I want to be able to embed the app itself and let people play with it.

I've seen a lot of interest in people wanting to include markdown in their Shiny apps. But how can I do the reverse?

I looked at using an iframe, but apparently those are disallowed for security concerns.

Comment: Since the app has to be served by shinyapp.io server, I don't see there is any way other than an iframe